# How to call startActivityForResult method to get result from another app

Tags: android, kotlin, android-intent, intentfilter

I am calling the startActivityForResult method from App 1 to get a result from app 2 but the setResult method on app 2 is not returning anything.

Code in App 1

```
val intent=packageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.example.colorpicker")
            if (intent!=null){
                intent.action
                val bundle=Bundle()
                bundle.putString("sendColor","")
                intent.putExtras(bundle
                intent.setFlags(0)
                startActivityForResult(intent,2)
            }
```

Code in App 2

```
val intent=Intent()
val returnBundel=Bundle()
returnBundel.putInt("red", redText.text.toString().toInt()). 
returnBundel.putInt("green", 
greenText.text.toString().toInt())
returnBundel.putInt("blue", 
blueText.text.toString().toInt())
intent.putExtras(returnBundel)
intent.setFlags(0)
this.setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK,intent)
this.finish()
```

Answer (score 0):

I've faced this issue before, and the solution was not to call finish immediately after setting the result.

try this code snippet:

```
    setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, resultIntent);

    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            finish();
        }
    }, 100);
```